# JAVA - Resume/Pause https connection download

Tags: java, https, download, zip, desktop

I have a code like this

```
    public void downloadZip(String URL, String fileName) {

    try {
        java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(save + "/" + fileName);
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(b)) >= 0) {
            out.write(b, 0, count);
        }
        out.flush(); out.close(); in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite it to be able to continue/stop loading?

Comment: You will find that StackOverflow will be most helpful to you when you explain your problem as specifically as possible. This question looks like you are asking us to do your work for you. Please try some solutions yourself and tell us what you have already tried, why it doesn't work, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a separate thread using SwingUtilities. In the GUI thread you set a flag if you want to stop. If you want to resume, you can reopen the URL and use the skip method of the InputStream to start from where you left. To pause, resume you can use signals. See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html.

You need to educate yourself about multi-threading.

Comment: how can i use skip the method InputStream? you have tutorial?

Comment: There is a method called skip that takes the number of bytes you want to skip.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_skip.htm